# How to mock object in mocha unittest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

In my reactjs component I have a method called getContainer(doc) with this line:

```
  let w = Math.max(doc.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth);
```

It takes 1 parameter called doc: htmldocument. In my mocha unittest I got:

```
let mockDoc =  {documentElement: {clientWidth:100}}
let res = wrapper.instance().getContainer(mockDoc);
```

When I run the test I still get an error , how can I fix this?

Error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use an visual dom library like jsdom,for more details you can see [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).it is simple to use.here is a demo by [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html)